# How to delete/rename a file from a multi-part winrar archive

Tags: windows-10, archiving, winrar

I created a 7 part winrar archive with videos in it, but there is no option to delete or rename a selected video. How can I delete/rename them without extracting the entire archive?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a program that can do it.

Normally it's better to extract the archive, rename what you want and compress it again.

Or trying to use some commands thru the jar-tool from java and 7z, it do not extract the whole archive but only the files needed. To test backup your file.

> jar tvf file.zip  (to see the content and the file you want to change)
>
> jar xvf file.zip folderOfFile/file.mp4 & cd folderOfFile & ren file.mp4 file2.mp4 & cd .. & jar -uvf file.zip folderOfFile/file2.mp4 (or trying the single commands)

You could then delete the original file with 7z.

> 7z d file.zip folderOfFile/file.mp4

Comment: Note that the author said: "How can I delete/rename them **without extracting the entire archive**?"